# Дубли транзакций в Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Есть магазин, сделан Data Layer на странице успешной покупки, при обновлении страницы он уже не выводится (хранится один раз в сессии). Стали появляться дубли заказов в аналитике, нашел такое решение: https://www.thyngster.com/preventing-duplicate-transactions-in-universal-analytics-with-google-tag-manager/

Дубли идут все равно, при чем по отчетам выяснили, что только на Android и iOS и не у всех, только у части заказов.
Думаю что браузер как-то кеширует страницу с data layer, и при каких-то условиях выполняет снова js.

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась связана с настройками Apache: странице checkout success было разрешено кеширование.

Answer (score 0):

Если у пользователей есть возможность повторно попасть на страницу подтвержденного заказа с другого устройства (например, вы отправляете ссылку на такую страницу на почту) и на этой странице записываются данные о транзакции в dataLayer, то вы получите дубли транзакций.

Лучше проблемы дублей транзакций решать не через cookies в браузере, а через настройку логики бекенда - не должны данные о транзакции передаваться в dataLayer при любой повторной загрузке страницы подтвержденного заказа.

Answer (score 0):

я решал это так.

1. я хронил данные в сессиях а не в куки. Поскольку аккаунты
   синхронизируются, а куки лежат на стороне клиента, и куки удаляются
   только после отработки страницы, значит если человек зашел с
   компьютера, а после с мобильного устройства  - будет отправленно 2
   datalayer.
2. Нужно закрыть доступ к странице успешеной покупки со
       всех фронтов))) кроме 1, это корзина, или дургая часть , где
       финалится покупка.